# Firebase Magic Link in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm working on [Firebase's Passwordless Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) using Android. The Magic Link is received via email, but clicking it only opens the specified URL in Chrome, instead of my app. Here's how things are setup on the client, let me know if relevant code is missing. I've also posted [.well-known/assetlinks.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#app_links) at the root of my site hoping it would help, to no avail.

```xml
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="es0329.com" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

```kotlin
// Screens.kt
sealed class Screens {
  object Feed : Screens(
    route = "feed",
    title = R.string.feed,
    icon = Icons.Rounded.TravelExplore
) {
  val deepLinks: List<NavDeepLink> = listOf(
    navDeepLink {
      uriPattern = "$deepLinkBaseUrl$route"
      action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    })
  }
}

companion object {
  const val deepLinkBaseUrl = "https://es0329.com/"
}
```

```kotlin
// AuthStore.kt
actionCodeSettings {
  url = "${Screens.deepLinkBaseUrl}feed"
  handleCodeInApp = true
  setAndroidPackageName(
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
    INSTALL_IF_NOT_AVAILABLE,
    BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
  )
}
```

```kotlin
// NavGraph.kt
composable(
  route = Feed.route,
  deepLinks = Feed.deepLinks
) { 
  BreweryList() 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest's opening *intent-filter* tag was missing the `autoVerify` attribute.

```xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="es0329.com" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: out of curiosity, did you have any trouble dealing with the deep link generated by the magic link?

Comment: @MarcoAntonio Yep, I'm trying to deal with it. The app wakes and I'm able to log the link in `Activity.onResume`, but it logs `null` within the Composable.

Comment: I had the same issue, but gave up on trying to find an answer, specially on how hard it is to debug these actions. So, I just dealt with the token within activity itself